# Anaconda installed for all users still trying to create path in user directory (Windows 10)

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, windows-10, whitespace

I made the rookie mistake of putting a space in my Windows user name, i.e. `User Name`

For this reason Anaconda would not open when I came to install it. To get around this, I tried to install it for all users in `C:\Anaconda`. (running the installation as administrator).

However, when I come to run `Anaconda Prompt`, it is unable to launch Anaconda (or Spyder etc.) stating:

`Failed to create temp directory "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-<RANDOM>\"`

The default path in the prompt is also set to `C:\Users\User Name>`

What exactly is the point of the 'Install for all users' option if it still tries to interact with the user directory?

Is there a way to get around this short of renaming the user profile (which seems to be fraught with the possibility of things breaking) or migrating to a completely new profile?

Edit: Following advice in this thread: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9757 I modified the `activate.bat` file which seems to fix the above error, but I still can't launch Anaconda due to some other error that doesn't occur when using Anaconda on a different user profile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
        
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module> from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION # analysis:ignore 
    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
    
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module> sys.exit(main()) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 112, in main from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app File 
        
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 19, in <module> from qtpy import PYQT5 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module> raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found') qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found.
```